# Why is $A$ uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis, infinity

[image]
I don’t understand the reasoning statement in the box.

Comment: For some context, it's called [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement in the box says the following:

If $X\subset A$ and $X$ is countable then $X \ne A$.

This shows that $A $ is uncountable since if you assume that $A$ is countable then $A\subset A$ so by the statement we proved, $A\ne A$ which is of course impossible.

Comment: So why bother proving “every countable subset of A is a proper subset of A?” Using proof by contradiction from the beginning would be a more straightforward way.

Comment: Yes, you can start the proof as follows: suppose that $A$ is countable. With the above reasoning you will get some $s \in A$ with $s \notin A,$ which is absurd.

Comment: you are right, the statement  $A$ is uncountable and the statement if $X\subset A$ is countable then $X\ne A$ are equivalent. @John